# Passing parameters retrieved from api call to Custom Validator in FormBuilder

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-formbuilder

In the component, I use `formBuilder` for `Angular Reactive Forms`

I get the example code from [this post](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-custom-validators-in-angular)

```
min = 10;
max = 20;
ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(8)]),
        age: new FormControl(null, [ageRangeValidator(this.min, this.max)])
    });
}
```

The custom validation is defined in function `ageRangeValidator`

```
function ageRangeValidator(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if (control.value !== undefined && (isNaN(control.value) || control.value < min || control.value > max)) {
            return { 'ageRange': true };
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

In case, `min` and `max` are got from api call. How can to pass them to function custom validator?

Comment: the api call main reason is to get these values or is it used more globally (do you just need to make it before initializing the form)?

Answer (score 1):

FormControl API provide [setValidators](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalidators) method. Which you can use to set Validator dynamically. Inside subscribe call back you can call setValidators something like this:

**Try this:**

```
 ..subscribe((result)=>{
    this.age.setValidators([ageRangeValidator(result.min,result.max)]);
    this.loginForm.get('age').updateValueAndValidity();    
  })
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6dhye)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the answer of Chellappan, but if you are going to change the value of max and min along the live of app angular, another way is that the function validator belong to the component and bind to this

```
//this function IN the component
ageRangeValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      if (control.value !== undefined && (isNaN(control.value) ||
          control.value < this.min ||control.value > this.max)
      ) {
        return { ageRange: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }

  //and when create the component
  age: new FormControl(15, [this.ageRangeValidator().bind(this)]) //<--see the bind(this)
```